# Incremental Auth for the GMAIL api

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail-api, google-signin, google-oauth

Google sign-in allows incremental permissions.   Can it be also be used to increment to the Gmail API?

Google Sign-in Incremental auth page:  https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth

Gmail API auth page:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

Comment: What's your usecase?

Comment: Start with Google + auth and once the user has an account with the system, then they can decide if they want to authorize access to their email so that system can read and send emails on their behalf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
Incremental auth allows auth scopes to be added to an already-logged-in user.

For example, to add permission to read a user's emails, the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly" will need to be additionally requested, as described in the doc.